# Unable to compile crypto for SHA-256 hashing on Devc

Tags: dev-c++, crypto++

```
#include <..\cryptopp\dll.h>
#include <..\cryptopp\sha.h>
#include <..\cryptopp\hex.h>
#include<..\cryptopp\files.h>

#include <iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;
using namespace CryptoPP;

const int MAX_PHRASE_LENGTH=250;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

CryptoPP::SHA256 hash;
byte digest[ CryptoPP::SHA256::DIGESTSIZE ];
std::string message = "Hello World!";

hash.CalculateDigest( digest, (const byte*)message.c_str(), message.length());

CryptoPP::HexEncoder encoder;
std::string output;
encoder.Attach( new CryptoPP::StringSink( output ) );
encoder.Put( digest, sizeof(digest) );
encoder.MessageEnd();

std::cout << "Input string: " << message << std::endl;
std::cout << "SHA256: " << output << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

errors

Compiler: Default compiler
Executing  g++.exe...
g++.exe "C:\Users\Pr\Desktop\Work\encrypt\sha256\sampeSHA256.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Pr\Desktop\Work\encrypt\sha256\sampeSHA256.exe"    -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\include"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\backward"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\mingw32"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include"   -L"C:\Dev-Cpp\lib" 
In file included from C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward/..\cryptopp/seckey.h:8,
                 from C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward/..\cryptopp/rijndael.h:7,
                 from C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward/..\cryptopp/aes.h:4,
                 from C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward/..\cryptopp\dll.h:11,
                 from C:\Users\Pr\Desktop\Work\encrypt\sha256\sampeSHA256.cpp:1:
C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward/..\cryptopp/cryptlib.h:277: error: function `std::string CryptoPP::NameValuePairs::GetValueNames() const' definition is marked dllimport.
C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward/..\cryptopp\/cryptlib.h:283: error: function`bool CryptoPP::NameValuePairs::GetIntValue(const char*, int&) const' definition is marked dllimport.
C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward/..\cryptopp/cryptlib.h:287: error: function `int CryptoPP::NameValuePairs::GetIntValueWithDefault(const char*, int) const' definition is marked dllimport.
C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward/..\cryptopp\/cryptlib.h:291: error: function`static void CryptoPP::NameValuePairs::ThrowIfTypeMismatch(const char*, const std::type_info&, const std::type_info&)' definition is marked dllimport.
C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward/..\cryptopp/cryptlib.h:301: error: function `void CryptoPP::NameValuePairs::GetRequiredIntParameter(const char*, const char*, int&) const' definition is marked dllimport.

In file included from C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward/..\cryptopp/aes.h:4,
                 from C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward/..\cryptopp\dll.h:11,
                 from C:\Users\Pr\Desktop\Work\encrypt\sha256\sampeSHA256.cpp:1:
C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward/..\cryptopp/rijndael.h:15: error: function `static const char* CryptoPP::Rijndael_Info::StaticAlgorithmName()' definition is marked dllimport.

In file included from C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward/..\cryptopp\dll.h:16,
                 from C:\Users\Pr\Desktop\Work\encrypt\sha256\sampeSHA256.cpp:1:
C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward/..\cryptopp/des.h:58: error: function `static const char* CryptoPP::DES_EDE2_Info::StaticAlgorithmName()' definition is marked dllimport.

C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward/..\cryptopp/des.h:82: error: function `static const char* CryptoPP::DES_EDE3_Info::StaticAlgorithmName()' definition is marked dllimport.

In file included from C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward/..\cryptopp\dll.h:37,
                 from C:\Users\Pr\Desktop\Work\encrypt\sha256\sampeSHA256.cpp:1:
C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward/..\cryptopp/skipjack.h:15: error: function `static const char* CryptoPP::SKIPJACK_Info::StaticAlgorithmName()' definition is marked dllimport.

Execution terminated

Comment: Can you post the command you're using to compile your program?

Comment: Executing  g++.exe...
g++.exe "C:\Users\Pr\Desktop\Work\encrypt\sha256\sampeSHA256.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Pr\Desktop\Work\encrypt\sha256\sampeSHA256.exe"    -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\include"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\backward"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\mingw32"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include"   -L"C:\Dev-Cpp\lib"

Comment: You're not linking to the cryptopp library there are you?  Shouldn't there be a `-lcryptopp` in the command?

Comment: it says -lcryptopp not found, should I point it to a specific object file or folder ?

Comment: `-lcryptopp` is telling g++ to link to the CryptoPP library.  It could be called something like `libcryptopp.a` or `cryptopp.so` - I'm not sure - I don't use g++ on Windows.  I take it you've already built CryptoPP?  If so, just locate the library and pass the path to the directory as a `-L` flag (like you've already got for `-L"C:\Dev-Cpp\lib"`.  I think pthread is also a dependency, you may also need to add `-lpthread` to your command.

Comment: It could also be called libcrpyto++ (Debian and Ubuntu, I believe). Fedora and Red Hat call it libcryptopp. See [Distributions Offering Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Linux#Distributions_Offering_Crypto.2B.2B)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `#include <..\cryptopp\dll.h>`

As Fraser said, use `-L<path to Crypto++>`.

As Fraser said, use either `-lcryptopp` or `-lcrypto++`. The one you use depends on what you have. By default, its `-lcryptopp`.